# fine grained multi core thread execution measurement on linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, cpu-usage, profiler

I'd like to have detailed insight into the running of a multi-threaded application (written in C++), and see in detail how much time each thread is spending on what CPU core.

I've looked at some tools like perf, or hcprof, but haven't found anything that would accomplish what I'm looking for.

What am I missing?

Any pointers welcome.

Akos

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing to much. Try LttNG it gives you kind of a scope into the execution.
The following link describes well what is it doing.
https://blog.selectel.com/deep-kernel-introduction-lttng/
LttNG has a quite steep learning curve.

Perf if ok but it gives you more of a ocupancy grid the a time profile. Are you using FlameGraps?

Please read this post http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-07-08/choosing-a-linux-tracer.html  it will give you a hint what tools do what.

As last a word of advice. In such systems everything is a problem, from building flags drivers to coding style for synchronization or memory management. You must be precise and meticulous in you profiling.